# Export maven with google dependency

Tags: java, api, maven, youtube, export

Currently I'm working on a discord bot with YouTube API as dependency. I want the bot to run 24/7 so I arranged a server for that. Since I added YouTube API as dependency is exporting as runnable jar probably not the best option since YouTube API is very big. Any ideas how to still be able to run the bot on the server?

Comment: not sure what is the question. youtube dependency is like 20mb. how small is your server? why it cannot handle 20mb of dependency inside a `fat jar`

Comment: There must be some other problem if you're finding that a server can't handle YouTube API. How do you think people normally use it?

Comment: Okay my bad it is indeed 20mb. I thought it was more :P       Thanks for the help :)